# How to send information to a file?

Tags: java, file

How can I save my data to a file?

This is what happens when I click a button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {

        if (f.getActionCommand() == Action.BUTTON1.name()){

            JButton knapp = (JButton) f.getSource();
            knapp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(upptagen));
            boka--;

        }
    }
```

There are 117 buttons and when I click on a specific button I want the button to be stored in a file so I can remember it the next time I run main.

The empty file is located at "src/assets/data"

Comment: Make a ([serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)) class to hold the clickstate of the buttons, then serialize it, when app closes. If it exists, deserialize it at start of the app to restore clickstate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going down the wrong path. Most likely, you are **not** interested in "storing" whole buttons.

Instead, your application allows the user to change specific properties of a button.

Meaning: you could read/write ordinary Java [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) to solve that problem. On startup, you read that property file and adapt your buttons according to the information in that file; and when the user asks for any changes, you update the properties; and write them back into the property file on your drive.